# Redirect all 404 errors excluding specific 404 urls to homepage using htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am currently renovating my website which has 1000s of pages; which requires changes to urls.

1. I want to 301 permanent redirect ALL 404 errors to website homepage say www.domain.com except some specific 404 URLs.
2. And I want to 301 permanent redirect those specifc excluded 404 URLs (in no.1) to another URL.

I tried following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about-us0.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/contact_us0.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^about-us0\.html$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/about\.html" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^contact-us0\.html$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/contact\.html" [R=301,L]
```

But when I browse to www.domain.com/about-us0.html or www.domain.com/contact_us0.html; google chrome says that "This webpage has a redirect loop".

Is there something I am doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

---

For redirecting without carring query string:

```
http://domain.com/prod/species.php?action=3&file_id=30
```

to

```
http://domain.com/species-30.php
```

AND

```
http://domain.com/prod/species.php?action=3&file_id=101
```

to

```
http://domain.com/species-101.php
```

I did something like this (below) which is working fine. Is there any changes that requires in this?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=3&file_id=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^prod/species\.php$ /species-%1.php? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(about|contact).*?\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(contact|about)-us0\.html$ http://www.domain.com/$1.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Is it possible to redirect each following URLs to specific page by htaccess...                                                         `http://domain.com/prod/species.php                                   
http://domain.com/prod/species.php?action=3&file_id=101               
http://domain.com/prod/species.php?action=3&file_id=30`

Comment: Yes it can be done, where do you want to redirect them? Also with redirect do you want query string to be carried over?

Comment: I want to redirect `http://domain.com/prod/species.php?action=3&file_id=101 to http://domain.com/species-101.php and http://domain.com/prod/species.php?action=3&file_id=30 to http://domain.com/species-30.php` ..... I don't want query string to be carried over. Also above URLs with query string are 404 so I also want to exclude them in 404.

Comment: Hi I just came back to this question. Do you still want a solution OR figured it out?

Comment: Let me know your thoughts by leaving a comment here.

Comment: I left an answer below. Can you please check if it is fine? Also, I posted another question with variables problem. I will appreciate if you can check that as well.

Comment: I don't see your other question. This is the only question you have right?